# Как обрабатывать запрос от веб-сервиса Soap + SpringBoot

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, soap, веб-служба

Каков алгоритм действий по обработке запроса от web-service **SOAP** ?

Я разрабатывают сервер, использую для разработки **Spring Boot**, а в качестве сборщика **Maven**.

Мой сервер выступает в качестве клиента, к удаленному веб-серверу (**SOAP**). Я должен от удаленного веб-сервиса получить **XML**-конверт, разобрать данные изменить, упаковать в **XML** и отправить обратно...

Как это можно организовать и еще настроить валидацию входящего **XML** и в случае обнаружения ошибки, я должен бросить Exception, затем должен быть сформирован пакет с **XML** в котором будет выслано сообщение об ошибке. Это нужно сделать автоматически (то есть формирование и отправка такого XML-пакета на основании брошенного **exception**)

Подскажите примеры...

Я использую **SpringBoot** 2.x + Maven

Answer (score 0):

- вы должны получить или создать xsd-Файл
- подключить плагин и настроить
- описать класс, на основе которого будет автоматически создан WSDL
- написать класс, который выполняет роль Конечной точки (такое же назначение как и у RestController)
  Данный класс будет принимать запросы от клиентов, обращаться на слой бизнес-логики для обработки данных и формировать обратный ответ клиенту

Здесь много примеров.

https://www.javaspringclub.com/publish-and-consume-soap-web-services-using-spring-boot-part-1/